# Pass a local file in to URL in Java

Tags: java, url, junit

How do I create a new `URL` object using a local file, for the purpose of unit tests?

Answer (score 332, accepted):

```
new File(path).toURI().toURL();
```

Comment: For java 7+:
Paths.get("path","to","stuff").toUri().toURL()

Answer (score 54):

Using Java 11:

```
Path.of(string).toUri();
```

Using Java 7:

```
Paths.get(string).toUri();
```

To convert to the old-school URL class (why?), add `.toURL()`. Note there is a difference in the string output. The modern `URI::toString` begins with `file:///` (the traditional URL syntax) while the nearly-deprecated `URL::toString` with `file:/` (the modern URI syntax). Weird

Comment: "...a URI begins with file:/// but a URL with file:/ ..."

Is that the case for both Windows and Linux?

Comment: @ptntialunrlsd That is a good question. I haven't checked, but I would guess yes.

Comment: No. An URL is just a special case of an URI. A file URI starts with "file://" and then lists the host (generally omitted), followed by "/" and the path "foo/bar" (generally meant to be read as an absolute path). Thus "file:///foo/var". An URI that looks like "file:/foo/bar" is incorrect. See also: [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Thank you for the explanation of URIs, but that doesn't answer **ptntialunrlsd**'s question. What does '...toURL().toString()' produce on Linux? Also, I've reverted your edits because they made my answer more wordy without changing the meaning.

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky It's best to leave pointers to the Oracle javadoc in though.. easier to click through to `java.nio.file.Paths`. Also, please be sure to make clear that you mean the _implementations_ in "URI vs URL". Anway `java.net.URL.toString()` produces the same thing on Unix, as it must. It only displays one "/"  which is _very wrong_ (see [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme)). I guess this is in Java because of reasons, better use `java.net.URI`. It correctly generates "file://[host]/" on a call to `.toString()`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer Actually, URIs (RFC 3986, RFC 8089) allow the single-slash `file:/path` form, but URLs (RFC 1738) don't. 

Answer (score 43):

```
new File("path_to_file").toURI().toURL();
```

Answer (score 23):

```
new URL("file:///your/file/here")
```

Comment: where `/your/file/here` is an absolute path to a file on Unix/Linux. On Windows it would be different I think.

Comment: That's not very clever, since you have to handle the escaping of characters which are not allowed in URLs yourself. On Windows (and potentially other operating systems), you also have to modify the path separator from the native path to the file.

Comment: `new URL("file:my.properties");`

Comment: While this is correct, it is not portable as it depends on absolute paths.

Comment: On Windows the following worked for me: `file:///C:\\file.zip`

Answer (score 10):

```
File myFile=new File("/tmp/myfile");
URL myUrl = myFile.toURI().toURL();
```

Answer (score 5):

have a look here for the full syntax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme
for unix-like systems it will be as @Alex said `file:///your/file/here` whereas for Windows systems would be `file:///c|/path/to/file`

Comment: Don't do that manually. `File.toURI().toURL()`is the way to go

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd sometimes you don't have a choice, like when it is in a `.properties` file.

Comment: @ArtB I don't see how that makes a difference

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd, this question/answer comes up when you search for `java file url`, which in my case means that I was searching for the format of a `file://` URL, in Java, for use in a `.properties` file, or to type in manually, etc.

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd sometimes you don't have access to the source code, just to the property, and `file://` is unfortunately necessary. Being system dependent is not such a huge issue since it's a mutable property.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
[AnyClass].class.getResource(filePath)
```

Comment: but only if that file exists within the classpath

Comment: If the "filePath" can be found in a jar, the resulting URL is like `jar:file:/home/user/a/b/c/foo.jar!/com/example/stuff/config.txt`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with Java on Linux. The following possibilities are OK:

```
file:///home/userId/aaaa.html
file:/home/userId/aaaa.html
file:aaaa.html  (if current directory is /home/userId)
```

not working is:

```
file://aaaa.html
```