# File Fetching from file directory rather than HTTP URL

Tags: java, file, httpconnection

Previously, my code was developed to fetch the file content from the HTTP URL like "http://storage.googleapis.com/abc". But, requirement just slightly has got changed now and demands that instead of using HTTP URL link, it should need to use file directory location of the server. (i.e., `/var/puru/abc`).

So, is there any proper or significant way to do and fulfill the requirement without much-doing changes to my existing code drastically?

I have provided the code sample here, which provide the file URL(baseUrl) that is using http URL actually.

```
private URL getFileUrl(String fileName) throws MalformedURLException {

        try {
            Date dateObj = dateFormatter.parse(date);
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTime(dateObj);
            return new URL(baseUrl, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "/" + fileName);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Please suggest, and guide me.

Comment: please share some sample codes . so it will more understandable

Comment: We can't tell you what needs to be changed if you don't post the original code.

Comment: You didn't include the code that creates the base HTTP URL.

Comment: Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098472/pass-a-local-file-in-to-url-in-java

Comment: Thanks, BTW baseUrl was just the http URL that's why I didn't include the code.