# How to use path from FileChooser for image's absolute path?

Tags: java, file, javafx, path, filechooser

What i want is when user choose one image with File Chooser to display it on screen.

```
            FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
            File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

            if(selectedFile != null)
            {
               // Absolute path from file is: G:\Stvari\Daki Matura\IMG_6746.JPG
                Image img = new Image(selectedFile.getAbsolutePath());
                iv.setImage(img);

            }
```

When i do it this way i get Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
This absolutepath from file chooser doesnt work. But if i change it

from: "G:\Stvari\Daki Matura\IMG_6746.JPG"

to:  "file:///G://Stvari//Daki Matura//IMG_6746.JPG"  Then it works perfeclty.

Is there any way to solve this problem so i dont need to edit path ?

Comment: @Tunaki Answer `.toURI().toURL();` in the so called [duplicate question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098472/pass-a-local-file-in-to-url-in-java) doesn't work for `Image`.  `Image` doesn't have an constructor that takes `URL` as parameter.

Comment: Really couldnt find his answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just call an appropriate method on the URL to convert it to the required string, i.e. `file.toURI().toURL().toExternalForm()` (or equivalently `.toString()`). I don't think that extra step makes it a different question.

Comment: @James_D Well if it'd make a different question I'm not sure, there's certainly more to it than just an extra step though:  If you look at `URI.toURL()`, it'll `return new URL(toString())`, passing the String we actually want, overload three constructors, and do a load of stuff in the URL constructor.  Then, `URL().toString()` eventually calls the `toString()` of the stream protocol handler.  Why would you do all that extra work if it's not necessary?

Comment: @James_d ... And if you use `toURI().toURL().toWhatever()`, you'll have to deal with `MalformedURLException`, while `.toURI().toString()` simply doesn't throw.  I doubt `MalformedURLException` is very useful when selecting a file with `FileChooser`?   If that's true, I'd rather keep it simple and not have an unnecessary try/catch either.

Answer (score 0):

Use `File.toURI().toString()`,

```
    FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
    File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

    if (selectedFile != null) {
        Image img = new Image(selectedFile.toURI().toString());
        iv.setImage(img);
    }
```