# Trying to add an image to a label but won't work?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jlabel, embedded-resource

I'm trying to add the image "Pic.png"  to this JLabel "label1" and display it on the JPanel "panel1" on a JFrame "window1". But it when I hit run it doesn't display my image. Anyone help? (I read about adding it to the source file or something but I'm not really sure what I'm doing because I'm new to Java. Will it not be able to access the picture without the image being in the source?)

```
public class UIForIshidaQuery {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running...");

        JFrame window1 = new JFrame();
        window1.setVisible(true);
        window1.setSize(1080, 720);
        window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel1 = (JPanel) window1.getContentPane();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        panel1.setLayout(null);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\BC03\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\Other\\Pic.png");
        label1.setIcon(image);
        label1.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);
        panel1.add(label1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `new File("C:\\Users\\BC03\\Pictures\\Saved Pictures\\Other\\Pic.png").exists()` return true ?

Comment: See the examples cited [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) in the [tag:embedded-resource] tag.

Comment: Yes it returns true@Berger

Comment: @Cutter : you may use the `ImageIcon`'s constructor taking an URL, and retrieve the URL from your File's path, see : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098472/pass-a-local-file-in-to-url-in-java

Comment: @Berger If it's the right path, converting it to an URL will make no difference. In fact, it will also make no difference if it is the wrong path.

Comment: @Andrew Thompson : You're right, I misunderstood how the constructor with the String worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window should be set visible as the last call. Don't use `null` layouts<sup>1</sup>. This works.

```
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class UIForIshidaQuery {

    public static String url = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/gJmeJ.png";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
        System.out.println("Running...");

        JFrame window1 = new JFrame();
        window1.setSize(1080, 720);
        window1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel panel1 = (JPanel) window1.getContentPane();
        JLabel label1 = new JLabel();
        //panel1.setLayout(null);
        ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(new URL(url));
        label1.setIcon(image);
        //label1.setBounds(500, 500, 500, 500);
        panel1.add(label1);
        window1.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

1. Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).

Comment: The above information is correct, pixel perfect layout is difficult to achieve in Java Swing. So for the sake of just checking your image in the existing code you can run and try to maximize/minimize your window and you will see your image appearing which is not going to appear  instant when you run the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA:

1. Right click your project root directory and select New > Directory;
2. Call the new directory 'resources' for example;
3. Right click the newly made directory and select Mark Directory As > Resources Root;
4. Add your image file in the directory;
5. Access your file properly:
   `CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("pic.png").getFile();`

The ImageIcon could be initialized like this:

```
File file = new File(CurrentClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("pic.png").getFile());
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(file);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(image);
```

Comment: I'm not using IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: I'm sorry, I missed the netbeans tag you've added. Still a good reference for other users using IntelliJ IDEA.