# Relative file system URL specification

Tags: java, url

In some unit tests initially we used such resource links for `java.net.URL` class

`"https://<host name>/<project name>/pom.xml"`

for loading test data. However, it doesn't work during offline development.

*How it's possible to specify relative from `test/java` folder URL in file system?*

I tried `"file:///../pom.xml"` but it brings to exception

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: \..\pom.xml (The system cannot find the file specified)`

If I specify `"file://..\\pom.xml"` I receive

`Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ..`

Comment: Try `file:../pom.xml`.

Comment: Read <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6098472/pass-a-local-file-in-to-url-in-java">this</a>. I tthink it's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is to use `file:` protocol specification without following slashes. As JUnit consider as a root the project folder in my case correct link to pom.xml is simple `file:pom.xml`